# python virtualenv.el no longer works in emacs after updating python-mode

Tags: python, emacs, virtualenv

I upgraded from `python-mode.el-6.1.2` to `python-mode.el-6.1.3` and my `M-x virtualenv-activate venvname` no longer activates the virtual environment in my emacs `*Python*` buffer.  This same keystroke used to load the virtualenv.

My process for updating python-mode was only...

```
$ wget https://launchpad.net/python-mode/trunk/6.1.3/+download/python-mode.el-6.1.3.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf python-mode.el-6.1.3.tar.gz 
$ emacs init.el
```

And then changing

```
; python-mode
(setq py-install-directory "~/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.1.2")
(add-to-list 'load-path py-install-directory)
(require 'python-mode)
```

to the correct folder of:

```
; python-mode
(setq py-install-directory "~/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.1.3")
(add-to-list 'load-path py-install-directory)
(require 'python-mode)
```

Then reloading with `M-x load-file`

This is the only change I made that I can attribute the sudden change in behavior to.  Anyone have similar experiences or pointers for what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, this seemed to have been fixed by restarting emacs.  I thought re-loading the file would mean I didn't have to do that.  Anyway, problem solved.

Comment: Great to learn it's solved. Should this or another issue appear again, please consider a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

Answer (score 1):

I haven't maintained
[my virtualenv](https://github.com/aculich/virtualenv.el) package in a
long time since I use docker and LXC for a better virtual environment
for my development purposes that provides stronger isolation,
first-class network interfaces, and support for non-python stacks.

If you still want to work with virtualenv there are at least 3 newer,
actively maintained packages available on
[MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) that are superior to my old one
that have taken its place:

- [pyvenv](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv)
- [virtualenvwrapper](https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el)
- [python-environment](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-python-environment)